# change the images using runOnUiThread

Tags: android

Hi i am displaying the 2 imageViews if one image contain number 1(number1 image) second image show 2(image 2)
and again first image displayt the 2 image(number2) then second imageview display the 3 image(number 3 image)
second image view is displayed after some time of first image dispalying.for this i am using runOnUiThread concept.Please give me some suggestions to how two threads are write in runOnUiThread method .Give some sample code.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can solve your problem.

```
public class ImageSwithcer extends Activity
{
  Handler programHandler = new Handler()
  {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg)
    {
      /***********
       * Update your UI here ****************
       * 
       * like updating your image views
       */
    }
  };

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    super.onCreate();
    startImageSwicherThread();
  }

  public void startImageSwitcherThread()
  {

    Thread background = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
      public void run()
      {
        try
        {
          Thread.sleep(4000);
          progressHandler.sendMessage(progressHandler.obtainMessage());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
      }
    });

    // start the background thread
    background.start();
  }
}
```

Comment: Please try to post usefull code. Maybe update your code @ Handler programHandler != progressHandler[...] - variable missmatch.