# ImageView / Bitmap via AsyncTask Doesn't Show Properly

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Long time reader, first time poster. I'm very new to Android development and am having trouble getting images to show when using AsyncTask to insert ImageViews (containing Bitmaps) into a LinearLayout. This is all triggered in the onCreate() method of an Activity I have.

The ImageViews (+Bitmaps) are definitely getting added via AsyncTask to my LinearLayout parent. However, the images don't show properly when I start my Activity. Sometimes an image or two (out of 3+) will display and sometimes none will show. All the images display properly after I fiddle with the UI, such as by bringing up and hiding the keyboard. I suspect that the LinearLayout and/or ImageViews may not be resizing to contain and show all the new children, but I tried many combinations of invalidate() and requestLayout() at the places I marked as "LOCATION1" and "LOCATION2" in attempt to trigger redraws.

Would anyone help on ensuring all images are displayed properly after onCreate() and after each AsyncTask is complete? Thanks a bunch. I'll try to be succinct with my code snippets...

This is my layout XML. I am adding my ImageViews to the LinearLayout with id "horizontal":

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText
    ... />

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

This is some of my onCreate() code. Where I create an AsyncTask for every image I want displayed.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
LinearLayout horizontal = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.horizontal);
...
//an array of absolute file paths to JPGs in storage
ArrayList<String> images = report.getImageMain();
PhotoBitmapTask task = null; //extension of AsyncTask
for (int i = 0; i < images.size(); i++) {
    task = new PhotoBitmapTask(getApplicationContext(), horizontal, images);
    task.execute(i);
    //LOCATION1
}
...
}
```

This is my extension of AsyncTask.

```
//a bunch of imports
public class PhotoBitmapTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Bitmap> {

    private Context context;
    private WeakReference<ViewGroup> parent;
    private ArrayList<String> images;
    private int data;

    public PhotoBitmapTask(Context context, ViewGroup parent, ArrayList<String> images) {
        super();

        this.context = context;
        this.parent = new WeakReference<ViewGroup>(parent);
        this.images = images;
        this.data = 0;
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Integer... params) {
        data = params[0];
        return getBitmapFromFile(images.get(params[0]), 600, 600);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if (context != null && parent != null && result != null) {
            ViewGroup viewGroup = parent.get();
            if (viewGroup != null) {
                ImageView imageView = PhotoBitmapTask.getImageView(context);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
                viewGroup.addView(imageView);
                //LOCATION2
            }
        }
    }

    public static Bitmap getBitmapFromFile(String filePath, int maxHeight,
            int maxWidth) {
        // check dimensions for sample size
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);

        // calculate sample size
        options.inSampleSize = getSampleSize(options, maxHeight, maxWidth);

        // decode Bitmap with sample size
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
    }

    public static int getSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
            int maxHeight, int maxWidth) {
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int sampleSize = 1;

        if (height > maxHeight || width > maxWidth) {
            // calculate ratios of given height/width to max height/width
            final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height / (float) maxHeight);
            final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) maxWidth);

            // select smallest ratio as the sample size
            if (heightRatio > widthRatio)
                return heightRatio;
            else
                return widthRatio;
        } else
            return sampleSize;
    }

    public int getData() {
        return this.data;
    }

    public static ImageView getImageView(Context context) {
        // width and height
        final LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        // margins
        params.setMargins(20, 20, 20, 20);
        final ImageView view = new ImageView(context);
        view.setLayoutParams(params);
        // scale type
        view.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you inflating those ImageViews? Show the code you're using to inflate. Also remember that when you run code in onBackground, you can't do changes in the UI, because you're in an other thread.

Comment: post your complete PhotoBitmapTask code here

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this ? The UI thread is meant for UI such as image views. So you do not normally put these into an Async task.

Comment: @SergiCastellsaguéMillán, I'm not inflating the ImageViews at all. May I ask what that would do?

Comment: @RyanHeitner, I was under the impression that it was alright to call UI methods in onPostExecute() - I'll have to read more on this stuff.

Comment: It is ok as you say, just unusual. You need to synchronize with the user interface thread. onPostExecute() method synchronizes itself again with the UI thread and allows it to be updated. This is called by doInBackground() method finishes. So try use this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much headache and heartache, I found the answer. I did not mention it previously or search for it specifically because I didn't think it was relevant, but I'm using [Nuance's 360 SpeechAnywhere developer SDK](https://www.nuancehealthcaredeveloper.com/public/index.php) to include speech recognition in my app. Hopefully I'm not breaking the terms of my SDK license by saying this:

Every "recognition enabled" activity is supposed to have a custom View as the root in order to embed speech recognition controls and functionality. It turns out that this custom View does not always refresh its children, unless you instruct it to via the custom View's synchronize() function. Long story short, I called the View's synchronize() method once my AsyncTask finished, onPostExecute() ran, and Bitmap was added to the activity.

Answer (score -1):

In the AsynTask you work on UI changes.you can't do changes in the UI in background work.Use runOnUIThread always do computation on UI thread.It better depend on your easy of use.look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3414471/change-the-images-using-runonuithread).

Comment: I'm doing changes to the UI in AsyncTask.onPostExecute(). The API documentation indicates that it is "invoked on the UI thread after the background computation finishes". Anyways, that part of my code appears to work fine, I just need the ImageViews to display properly after the AsyncTask is done.